# Test case getting failed in the program of nth term of Geometric series

Tags: c++, c++14

The first two terms A and B are in geometric series, the code is supposed to find the nth term of the GP. It is getting executed for few test cases but getting failed for the test case where A=84; B=87; N=3. Can anyone please tell why is this happening, and even if this happens further, how can one solve this problem?

```
double termOfGP(int A,int B,int N)
{
int r;
r=(int)B/A;
return A * (int)(pow(r,N-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about what the value of `r` will be. In your case you have used an `int` to store the value of `r`, which will result in rounding down the actual result.

For the test that it failed, 87/84 = 1.0357. But your value of `r` will be rounded down to 1. Probably for the test cases that passed, you were lucky as the ratio didn't have any fractions.

You should use a double to store the value of r. Or you can modify the equation to be something like:

```
return A * (int)((double)(pow(B,N-1))/(double)(pow(A,N-1)));
```